# Reducer not writing to Redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a connect()ed container component where I try to write a list of books to my redux store. The action creator is available as props and state is mapped to props, however the book list never get into the redux store. readingList is still null instead of bookArray (the passed argument of the action creator). Can someone spot the issue here? Included relevant snippets here:

```
import { setReadingList } from '../actions/index';

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.setReadingList(bookArray);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    readingList: state.readingList
    }
  }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ setReadingList : setReadingList }, dispatch);
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReadingList);

/*-----------*/

./actions/index.js

export function setReadingList(readingList) {
    return {
      type : "SET_READINGLIST",
      payload : readingList
    };
  }

/*-----------*/

./reducers/index.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import readingList from './reading_list';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  readingList
});
export default rootReducer;

/*-----------*/

./reducers/reading_list.js

export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_READINGLIST":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you combining this reducer into your root reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling setReadingList in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount. Would also ensure bookArray is in scope.